# iTextSharp vertical SignatureAppearance

Tags: c#, itext, smartcard, signature

I'm signing a document with token certificate:

```
        var cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
        var chain = new[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };

        var externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");

        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(origem);

        var signedPdf = new FileStream(destino, FileMode.Create);

        var pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');

        var sig = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

        sig.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 0, 500, 50), pdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Signature");
        sig.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        sig.Layer2Text = "Assinado digitalmente por " + cert.SubjectName.Name;
        sig.Layer2Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 7);

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(sig, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

The signature text is rendered at bottom of the page. How can I change to a vertical mode, in the right part of document, outside the content margins?

thanks

Comment: Change the `new Rectangle(50, 0, 500, 50)` parameter of `sig.SetVisibleSignature`.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems does not change the text orientation.

Comment: *it seems does not change the text orientation* - No, it does not. did you imply that in "vertical mode"?

Comment: You right, the question asked was not good enought. I'm trying to figure out some way to put the text bottom-up in a vertical column. When printed, the content will be portrait and the signature in landscape orientation. I still don't know if I could explain it right.

Comment: Ok. iText allows you to generate an appearance for the signature all by yourself, e.g. in your "vertical mode". I don't know whether there is a supported easier way.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to get some vertically oriented signature, the rectangle in which to visualize the signature should be somewhat more vertically oriented. Thus, in place of your

```
sig.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 0, 500, 50), pdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Signature");
```

you should use something like

```
sig.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 0, 50, 500), pdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Signature");
```

Now you clarified in comments that not only the visualization rectangle should have a vertical orientation but that the text also should be drawn vertically. iText by default creates visualizations with horizontal text. Thus, you have to use customized appearances.

As I am more at home with iText/Java, this example to customize a `PdfSignatureAppearance appearance` is in Java. It should be easy to transform to iTextSharp/C#, though.

```
appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle, PAGENUMBER, SIGNATURENAME);

// customize appearance layer 2 to display text vertically
PdfTemplate layer2 = appearance.getLayer(2);
layer2.transform(new AffineTransform(0, 1, -1, 0, rectangle.getWidth(), 0));
Font font = new Font();
font.setColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
font.setSize(10);
ColumnText ct2 = new ColumnText(layer2);
ct2.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI);
ct2.setSimpleColumn(new Phrase("Signed by me, myself and I", font), 0, 0, rectangle.getHeight(), rectangle.getWidth(), 15, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

ct2.go();
```

This example draws "Signed by me, myself and I" vertically in the page area `rectangle`.

Comment: Good job! Thanks in advance. Just fews changes to C#, like sets to props: var ct2 = new ColumnText(layer2) { RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI };

Comment: Is there a way to appear on the most right side possible for all documents, portraits or landscape? Maybe calculated by doc width?

Comment: *to appear on the most right side* - you can get the rightmost coordinates from the cropbox of the page in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public bool drawVerticalText(string _text, Color _color, int _angle, int _size, int _left, int _top)
    {
        try
        {
            BaseColor bc = new BaseColor(_color.R, _color.G, _color.B, _color.A);
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            //int width = baseFont.GetWidth(_text);
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetColorFill(CMYKColor.RED);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, _size);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, _text, _left, document.Top - _top, _angle);
            cb.EndText();
            document.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can change the alpha value of the color, rotation angle (say, 45), text size and make a watermark to your document...

While above method uses DirectContent with absolute coordinates, the below method uses cell object with rotation property. Note that cell rotation can be multiple of 90, while with the 1st method you can have any angle...

```
    public void drawVerticalText2()
    {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        float[] widths = new float[] { 1.25f, 1.55f, 0.35f, 0.35f };
        table.SetWidths(widths);

        PdfPCell horizontalCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("I'm horizontal"));
        horizontalCell.Border = BORDERS.BOX;
        horizontalCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.AddCell(horizontalCell);

        PdfPCell horizontalMirroredCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("I'm horizontal mirrored"));
        horizontalMirroredCell.Border = BORDERS.BOX;
        horizontalMirroredCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        horizontalMirroredCell.Rotation = 180;
        table.AddCell(horizontalMirroredCell);

        PdfPCell verticalCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("I'm vertical"));
        verticalCell.Border = BORDERS.BOX;
        verticalCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        verticalCell.Rotation = 90;
        table.AddCell(verticalCell);

        PdfPCell verticalMirroredCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("I'm vertical  mirrored"));
        verticalMirroredCell.Border = BORDERS.BOX;
        verticalMirroredCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        verticalMirroredCell.Rotation = -90;
        table.AddCell(verticalMirroredCell);

        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
    }
```

[image]

enjoy!