# Vertical Digital Signature Appearance C# ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, signature, digital

I have code which digitally signs pdf file which displays the signature horizontally by default, but need the signature to be place Vertical position.

I have tried rotating the rectangle to 90 or 270 but didn't worked

Working code(Print signature horizontal position)

```
        X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);
        if (!cert.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Certificate does not have Private Key");
        }
        else
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            if (rsa == null)
            {
                if (rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice) //smartcard
                {
                    if ((rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName == CertificateDetails.KeyContainerName) && (rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName == CertificateDetails.ProviderName))
                    {
                        // MessageBox.Show("Certificate Match");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Certificate Provider Details.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        X509CertificateParser cp = new X509CertificateParser();
        X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(source);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, new
        FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);

        PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
        signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        signatureAppearance.Reason = reason;
        signatureAppearance.Location = location;

        signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50, 250, 250, 30), 1, signatureName);

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        pdfStamper.Close();
```

Expecting the output to display signature in vertical position.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given earlier.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042136/12237843