# c# Sign pdf document with logo on the left (itextsharp 3.1)

Tags: c#, winforms, itext, windows-forms-designer, sign

I´m signing a pdf document with digital certificate, using itextsharp 3.1.
Everything works fine, but I want to make some aspect changes that I don't know how they are made.

Currently, the logo (jpg image) is shown in the background of the signature, what I want is that the logo to appear to the left of the signature.
Thanks.

The code I am using is:

```
public void Sign(string SigReason, string SigContact, string SigLocation, bool visible)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputPDF);
    PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);

    st.MoreInfo = this.metadata.getMetaData();
    st.XmpMetadata = this.metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

    sap.SetCrypto(this.myCert.Akp, this.myCert.Chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
    sap.Reason = SigReason;
    sap.Contact = SigContact;
    sap.Location = SigLocation;

    sap.Image = Image.GetInstance(@"Logo.jpg");
    sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), st.Reader.NumberOfPages, null);

    st.Close();
}
```

The actual result is:

[image]

The expected result is:

[image]

Comment: why are you using a 13 year old library, for security purposes, when you can use a more recent version?

Comment: Because it works well and I don't know how to migrate it to a more recent version, I´m a begginer with c#.

Comment: I don't know about iTextSharp 3.1 (I started working with iText in its 2.x (Java) / 4.x (.Net) versions) but probably that version 3.1 already allows to customize the signature appearance completely like newer versions do. In newer versions you can retrieve a `PdfTemplate` via `sap.GetLayer(2)` on which you can draw any appearance you want. Related answers: [Use iText to create signature with complete own appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763043/1729265), [iTextSharp vertical SignatureAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042136/1729265) (code in Java but easy to port), ...

Comment: I looked on Github for the oldest known tag of iTextSharp, and that is 4.1.6. I cannot find an older version. Could you please tell me where you found iTextSharp 3.1? I would really like to know.

Comment: Hi Amedee, I downloaded the example from this website a long time ago: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14488/E-signing-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp